# React: Conditional expression for a function

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I have the following states in one of the components:

```
this.state = {
   num1: 0,
   num2: 0,
   num3: 0,
   num4: 0,
   num5: 0
}
```

A function `setNumber()` is getting a value from a Child component. The function needs to:

1. Check, if the first state is 0, then assign the value to it (and breaks). If the first state is not 0, check to see the second, if 0, then assigns the value. Continues with all the 5 states.
2. Check, if any of the states match the value of the function, if so, set that state 0.

Could you please help me to define the conditional expressions for this?

I assume, that this could be done also with a for loop and a state array, but can't figure out the code.

Comment: If you do step 2 after step 1, won't you just be resetting the state back to 0 since you just assigned it to the value passed to the function?

Comment: The function is triggered by a checkbox, hence, it needs to update the state accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, you need to use the [`prevState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

> prevState is a reference to the previous state. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from prevState.

the setState in your function should look like this

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  if (prevState.num1 == 0) {
    return { num1: value };
  } else if (prevState.num1 == value) {
    return { num1: 0 };
  } else if (prevState.num2 == 0) {
    return { num2: value };
  } else if (prevState.num2 == value) {
    return { num2: 0 };
  } else if (prevState.num3 == 0) {
    return { num3: value };
  } else if (prevState.num3 == value) {
    return { num3: 0 };
  } else if (prevState.num4 == 0) {
    return { num4: value };
  } else if (prevState.num4 == value) {
    return { num4: 0 };
  } else if (prevState.num5 == 0) {
    return { num5: value };
  } else if (prevState.num5 == value) {
    return { num5: 0 };
  }
  return {};
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed.